# How would you quantify quality?

Tags: project-management, game-development, quality

What should be the core functions of games which represents an excellent game? What quality goals it should achieve to become successful game?

Any concise formed answer will get me on track.

Comment: You'd likely get a better answer on the game development site.

Comment: Oh ok how to migrate this question? sorry thanks

Comment: This question is quite broad and vague, so I hesitate to migrate it. I checked with the users on [GameDev.SE] and they informed me it would be too vague and hard to answer. Demian's answer here is about as good as it can get. I recommend you browse GameDev and see if any existing questions (such as [this one](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2988/how-do-you-come-up-with-ideas-for-new-games)) help you out or post one of your own if you have a specific problem you need help with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an *insanely* difficult question to answer and unfortunately I don't have an answer for you (but this is longer than a comment, thus posting as an answer).

AFAIK, there are no metrics concerning methods to quantify the fun factor in a game *during the design and implementation phase*. Otherwise, you wouldn't have bombs and metacritic wouldn't be overly useful.

It's fairly easy to find out whether or not a game is fun *after* having played it: If you want to play it again, then you've achieved your goal. Having said that, even *this* metric is entirely subjective, so you'd need to focus test it against a broad audience before knowing whether or not you've achieved your goal.

My suggestion?

Find games that you enjoy playing (preferably ones that are popular and perhaps have a high'ish metacritic rating (although that's not *always* the end-all-and-be-all of how *fun* a game is)) and "borrow" ideas from it. Play others and "borrow" ideas from them. Throw together a design for a game and talk to a few people about it. Get their opinion.

If you have the time after that, throw together a prototype. Have some of your friends try it. Get feedback and *use it*. Then, look at implementing the real thing.

Comment: I guess I have got my answer lol, Nice explanation!